JavaScript changes won't effect the rasptank webserver
I recently bought the Adeept Rasptank project.
I was trying to do some changes on the website.
Here are some examples of I tried;
buttons:[[!1,"Grab","grab",85,"stop"],[!1,"Up","up",73,"UDstop"],[!1,"Loose","loose",79,"stop"],[!1,"Left","lookleft",74,"LRstop"],[!1,"Down","down",75,"UDstop"],[!1,"Right","lookright",76,"LRstop"],[!1,"HandUp","handup",80,"HAstop"],"",[!1,"ArmUp","armup",82,"Armstop"],[!1,"HandDown","handdown",186,"HAstop"],[!1,"ArmDown","armdown",70,"Armstop"]],cols:3 
I've changed "Grab", "Up" etc. and got some results but then I changed the others and nothing changed.
Now I reset the codes and do the same changes but nothing comes up.
